# Postman - Runner - How to View Exported Results - Fail to import collection run

Tags: postman

I have run my Collection.
I have Exported results "***API.postman_test_run.json" file using Export Results option into my local folder:

[image]

I closed the Runner tab (Run Summary) on Postman.
And then I tried to open (to Import) this json file somewhere in Postman in order to view these results again and I do not see how I can do that.
My question is - how I can view exported results in Postman?
Is it possible at all or I need to open results in some other application like Visual Studio Code?

Here is an update: I have found the icon Runner in the right bottom part of my Postman desktop.

[image]

I clicked on it and got an interface to import the previous collection runs:
[image]

[image]

However, when I click on button Import I am getting an error: Failed to import collection run.

[image]

What could be the reason of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written to the Postman Support and got an answer that this issue that I noticed of getting an error on importing of the run results (postman_test_run.json) is the one which exists on Postman.  They are working on it now.

Comment: The issues is now fixed by Postman group. Importing is working now.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Postman
- Click Import, click Choose Files and specify "***API.postman_test_run.json" from your pc.
  -An import success message appears for each collection imported
  -Click the Eye icon to setup an Environment
- Click Add
  -Enter an Environment name. for example, FTAPI
  -Copy your API Key from the email sent to you in the previous step
  -Enter a Key and a Value
  -Click Add

---

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I have an error on Postman when trying to import the file.

Comment: @Vladislav   https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/working-with-data-files/    checkout this link it might help you